# npm TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, npm, typeerror

after a clean install of windows, I installed node.js again but it hasn't worked since. I got a lot of errors when running `npm i` while it was working fine on my other computer.

Trying to solve this i tried a lot of  things like windows update tools and such but nothing worked. As a last resort i tried removing node js and reistalling it. This lead to an even more annoying issue than before: [errors from running `npm -v`][1]

this is the case with every single command I run. I've tried deleting caches by hand but I don't find much info about this problem because often when people get this error it is because of an error in their code.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How are you installing node?

Comment: i am downloading the installer from the node js website. When running I also check the box fro extra services

Comment: Do u had tried in a new Terminal window OR, after reboot the system?

also what do u get result of `node-v`

Answer (score 0):

In the node js download process, if nodejs is not available on your system, the installation takes place, if there is, the update process takes place in the nodejs version.

If the operating system is windows, I suggest you to download the lts version .msi and reinstall it with default settings. I think this action will also solve the error in npm